# Jquery - how get value ul when click on li?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Good day.

I have ul list on my page.
me need get value `ul` when i click on `li`.

Html:

```
.ddlist {
position: absolute;
width: 316px;
display: none;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-top: -3px;
}

.ddlist li {
list-style: none;
padding: 5px;
}


<ul id="list_t_railway" class="ddlist" style="display: block;">
   <li>Белорусский вокзал</li>
   <li>Казанский вокзал</li>
   <li>Киевский вокзал</li>
</ul>
```

For get value ul i use script:

```
$("#list_t_railway").on("click", function(){
      alert($(this).val());

    });
```

But i get empty value...

Tell me please why i get empty value and how write right?

P.S.: all script for test you can see **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/t7ruw/)**

Comment: what are you trying to get> the `.val()` looks for the `value` property of the element

Comment: `val()` function is only intended for `input/textarea/select` elements. what kind of value are you expecting from your `ul`?

Comment: what do you mean by value ? you want to know how many children of UL ? or value of children ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to `alert` the contents of the `li` element, you can add a click handler on all li elements.

```
$("#list_t_railway li").on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).text());

});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7ruw/2/

Answer (score 2):

`li` elements have no `value`, so `.val()` won't return anything. Also, there's no event handler bound to the `<li>` elements themselves:

```
$("#list_t_railway li").on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this it will give you same outpuy

```
$(document).on("click","#list_t_railway li", function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ul value then use this.

```
$("ul#list_t_railway li").on("click", function(){
 alert($("ul#list_t_railway").text());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list_t_railway li").on("click", function(){alert($(this).html());});
```